# Detect click in other iframes of the same application

Tags: iframe

I have three iframes in my application, and in one frame I have a div (suppose a menu) which toggles between hide and show on click of a particular icon. now what I want to do is to make it hide when I click anywhere in any one of the other frames. Any help with example.